# Trezor - Sign transaction without confirm button press

Tags: ethereum, bitcoin, trezor

Working on a project with an HD wallet.  We'll generate a new address for each incoming payment, then sweep those accounts into our master wallet.  (Needs to be this we as we must associate each incoming payment with certain data.)

This is setup and works fine.  BUT, when sweeping accounts, we have to sit there and press the trezor comfirm button every time.  With a lot of transactions, that can get tedious.  (Note:  We're using python and trezorctl tools now)

Is there a way to configure the trezor, or the data so that we don't need to press that confirm button each time?

Answer (score -1):

Not unless you compile a custom firmware.

Allowing confirmation-less signing would obviously open a huge security hole.